# Conditional views with binding not working

Tags: swift, view, binding, swiftui

I'm trying to implement two conditional views on a main view. The condition whether each view should be hidden or not, are stored inside the conditional views view model as a observed object. I don't get any errors and the hiding condition is getting updated (which you can see by the changing color of the view), but is apparently not passed to the main view.

(Same ViewModel for both views)

```
class ProjectsViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var showExtendedProjectsView: Bool = false

}
```

(Same example view for both)

```
struct ProjectsView: View {
    
    @ObservedObject var vm = ProjectsViewModel()
    
    var body: some View {
        
        Button(action: {
            self.vm.showExtendedProjectsView.toggle()
        }, label: {
            ZStack {
                Rectangle()
                    .foregroundColor(self.vm.showExtendedProjectsView ? Color.green : Color.red)
                Text("Press")
            }
        })
    }
}
```

**This part is not working:**

```
struct Test2: View {
    
    let view1 = ProjectsView()
    let view2 = ProjectsView()
    
    var body: some View {
        
        VStack {
            if !view2.vm.showExtendedProjectsView {
                view1
            } else {
                EmptyView()
            }
            
            if !view1.vm.showExtendedProjectsView {
                view2
            } else {
                EmptyView()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What does `let view1 = Test()` or `let view2 = Test()` look like? Since it appears you are getting the value from the model in one of those views.

Comment: Sorry, fixed the typo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want your `Test2View` to refresh itself, it needs to observe something (or its State needs to be changed). In this case the `Test2View` can observe its children' `ProjectsViewModels`:

```
struct Test2: View {
    let view1 = ProjectsView()
    let view2 = ProjectsView()

    @ObservedObject var vm1: ProjectsViewModel
    @ObservedObject var vm2: ProjectsViewModel

    init() {
        vm1 = view1.vm
        vm2 = view2.vm
    }

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            if !vm2.showExtendedProjectsView {
                view1
            } else {
                EmptyView()
            }

            if !vm1.showExtendedProjectsView {
                view2
            } else {
                EmptyView()
            }
        }
    }
}
```